# How can we change a non vertical line to an hyperbola while constructing a Voronoi diagram?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, voronoi-diagram

I've been reading this article about the Voronoi diagram that uses mapping to transform a line to a hyperbola and somehow couldn't understand how the mapping works since I tried to prove it.

Here's the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is $d(z)$ the distance of $z$ from the origin? If so, proving the lemma just requires some straightforward, though tedious algebraic manipulation: Parameterize a generic line, apply the transformation, then eliminate the parameter.

Comment: d(z) is the euclidean distance from z to a point p which is the center of the circle

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose in what follows that $d_P(z)=\sqrt{z_x^2+z_y^2}$.

Take a generic non-vertical line $l$ with equation $y=mx+q$. A point $P$ on $l$ has coordinates $P=(x,mx+q)$ and is mapped to 
$$
P'=\big(x,mx+q+\sqrt{x^2+(mx+q)^2}\big).
$$
Therefore the coordinates of $P'$ obey the equation $y=mx+q+\sqrt{x^2+(mx+q)^2}$, that is:
$$
y-(mx+q)=\sqrt{x^2+(mx+q)^2}.
$$
Squaring and simplifying gives
$$
x^2-y^2+2mxy+2qy=0,
$$
which is indeed the equation of a hyperbola.